# Is it possible to apply for a new UK visa, to start immediately after an existing one expires?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am currently holding a 6 month visitor visa until the 6th of March and I have traveled three times (each trip for 4-5 days) to the UK in last 4 months to attend conferences.

However, I am planning my next travel from the 7th of March for 2 weeks and I need to re-apply for a new visa.

As there will be no gap between the last date of the old visa (6th of March) and the starting date of the new visa (7th of March), will this cause any problem for the new visa application?

Comment: If you had stayed for the whole duration of the first visa, then it would most probably be a problem. However, given the short stays you made, I'm not sure I see a reason for them not to grant it, this is probably quite common. Make sure to include details of your upcoming trip in your application.